# How to store signed numbers with decimals in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Trying to store currency, that can be in the negative/postive, with decimals.  I've done much searching and found that using Decimal type in the model is the best way.  That doesn't seem to be signed thought.  I see you can store a signed integer (no decimals).  But I can't find any info on storing a signed, decimal number.

Since I'm not finding anything, I'm guessing you can't.
If so, how do you go about storing this kind of info?  Create a boolean attribute that describes if the amount is neg/pos?

Comment: What makes you think that decimals are not signed?

Comment: As an aside, using floating point numbers to represent currency amounts is one of those things which seems sensible but leads to horrible problems in the real world. Lack of precision and rounding errors accumulate. The general recommendation is to use integers for whatever precision you need. For example, do all computations in tenths of a cent, so $5.27 is represented as 5270. Only convert to decimal for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Decimal" type in CoreData uses the SQLite "Decimal" storage class, which is backed by the "Real" storage class.

This will support negative numbers at the store level:

```
sqlite> .tables
test
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE test (pk integer primary_key, d double, f float, r real);
sqlite> insert into test (d,f,r) values (-1.0, -1.5, -1.252853);
sqlite> select * from test;
|-1.0|-1.5|-1.252853
```

As you can see, SQLite correctly stores the value.

In your objective C code you will be working with the NSNumber class, which can be instantiated with negative decimals using the following code:

```
[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:-1.57];
[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:-1.57];
```

Comment: account.balance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-1.57];  I get error of "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSDecimalNumber *' from 'NSNumber'

Comment: `account.balance = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithString:@"-1.57"];` is the proper way to initialize decimals.

Comment: @thom_ek:  AHA!  I did try that at some point before you posted.  When fetching the data to display as NSDecimalNumber, I see the negative as -1.57.  How do you test this?  Meaning, if I wanted to test if the value is negative?

Comment: NSAssert1([number decimalValue] < 0.0, @"number is not actually negative: %@", number); or you can use STAssertTrue(...) if you're using a unit test.

Comment: If I understand NSAssert1 correctly, not what I'm looking for.  I just need a plain old if statement... I need something along the lines of, if number is negative, do this, if number = 0 or positive, do something else.  As I said, I can get a -1.57 from my fetch, but when I test, it doesn't seem to recognize the negative.

Comment: the key is to get the primitive value from the NSDecimalNumber storage class. You use one of the various methods (-intValue, -doubleValue, etc) to do this. if ([account.balance doubleValue] < 0.0) {} else if ([account.balance doubleValue] == 0.0) {} and so on...

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits:  PERFECT!!!  I actually understood that! lol   Worked for me, thanks!  Ok, so both you and thom_ek answered my questions.  How do both get credit?

Comment: other way is `if([account.balance compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]]==NSOrderedAscending) { // is negative }`. Personally I don't use compare: methods directly, but created some category methods like isLessThan:, isGreaterThan:, etc. It helps reading code.